# AWS/JSON/shell script: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, shell

I am running awscli through shell script with passing arguments($1, $2, $3) and I get below error -

*I am using the shell script for terraform local-exec call*

**Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)**

```
aws transfer tag-resource --arn "$1" --tags '[{"Key":key1, "Value":"$2"},{"Key":key2,"Value":/blah/"$3"}]'
```

I tried with adding double quotes to keys and values too.. but no luck

Can you suggest what is wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2 and $3 does not resolve under single quotes in shell. Probably you should escape double quotes inside double quote. Something like below,

`"[{\"Key\":key1, \"Value\":\"$2\"},{\"Key\":key2,\"Value\":/blah/\"$3\"}]"`